# 2nd level scope objects not updating in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

let's say I have a directive with scope: `{ childEntity: '=' }`

and the template includes

```
<input type="text" ng-model="childEntity.parent.someProperty">
```

when the input value changes, childEntity.parent.someProperty is not updated in the parent scope. Is this intentional and how can I fix it?

Edit:

Oaky I still couldn't reproduce the error in jsFiddle BUT I was able to make it work in my app by passing both childEntity and parent to the directive individually BUT making sure not to use `scope.childEntity.parent instead` of `scope.parent`

Comment: It should work well in this case. Can you share some of your code?

Comment: As stated bt dfsq, it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/ncgoev90/, unless it is childEntity.$property

Comment: actually [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ncgoev90/2/) is a better example but aparently it actually works...